FluentNHibernate: CamelCaseField vs ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField
Given the following class:
public class User {
  private IList<ActivationToken> _activationTokens;
  public virtual IReadOnlyList<ActivationToken> ActivationTokens => _activationTokens.AsReadOnly();
}

what should the correct FluentNHibernate mapping be and why?
HasMany( x => x.ActivationTokens ).Access.CamelCaseField( Prefix.Underscore );

or
HasMany( x => x.ActivationTokens ).Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField( Prefix.Underscore );

Tnx

The correct mapping is:
HasMany(x => x.ActivationTokens)
.Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
enter code here
Reason:

Your ActivationTokens property is read-only, so NHibernate needs to
access the backing field _activationTokens.
ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField tells NHibernate to use the
_activationTokens field but respect that the property is read-only.

